# Collect to list on specific condition or exit

Tags: java-stream

```
     if (response.getSubscriber().getGroups() != null) {
         List<SPMGetGroupResponse> groupResponses =  response.getSubscriber().getGroups()
                                .stream()
                                .map(groupId -> callGetGroupAPI(groupId))
                                .filter(r -> r.getResultCode() == CommonResult.SUCCESS.getResultCode())
                                .collect(toList());
```

Is there a way in streams to make the above stop the moment r.getResultCode is not SUCCESSFUL?

the stream equivalent of

```
List<SPMGetGroupResponse> groupResponses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String groupId : groupIds) {
        SPMGetGroupResponse grpResponse = callGetGroupAPI(groupId);
        if (grpResponse.getResultCode() == CommonResult.SUCCESS.getResultCode()) {
            groupResponses.add(grpResponse);
        } else {
            break;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard way in Java-8 to do this. In Java-9 new operation called `takeWhile()` was added for this purpose:

```
 List<SPMGetGroupResponse> groupResponses =  response.getSubscriber().getGroups()
                 .stream()
                 .map(groupId -> callGetGroupAPI(groupId))
                 .takeWhile(r -> r.getResultCode() == CommonResult.SUCCESS.getResultCode())
                 .collect(toList());
```

Some third-party libraries including my library [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) backported `takeWhile()`:

```
 List<SPMGetGroupResponse> groupResponses = StreamEx.of(response.getSubscriber().getGroups())
                 .map(groupId -> callGetGroupAPI(groupId))
                 .takeWhile(r -> r.getResultCode() == CommonResult.SUCCESS.getResultCode())
                 .toList();
```